# How to correctly perform side effects synchronization with doOnNext/doOnCompleted?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java

When I get some `Observable` which executes on background thread but want to perform some side effects in a current class which is created and used on main thread - is it ok to use a synchronized block in `doOnNext` to stay thread-safe?

I.e. something like this:

```
class MyClass {
   private final CustomObject information = new CustomObject();

   public Observable<?> func() {
     // runs on Schedulers.io(), but I don't neccessarily know it
     Observable<?> observable = someModule.getObservable();
     return observable
       .doOnNext(v -> {
          synchronized (this) {
            information.saveSomething(v);
          }
        });
   }

   public void otherFunc() {
      synchronized (this) {
        information.saveSomething("blah-foo-bar");
      }
   } 
}
```

I currently have no such code in my projects, but sometimes tricky situations arise:

- I know I could use `.observeOn(mainThread())` before `.doOnNext()`, but this would have the effect of modifying a whole downstream, which is not always wanted
- I just realized that another good solution would be to make CustomObject() immutable (but then a `final` modifier will need to go away - is it ok?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's okay to do `synchronization` if you need to, just keep in mind that it will affect downside part of the chain in terms of performance if you won't move it to different thread.

Another possible solution for your case will be to not apply `observeOn(mainThread())` but do it manually inside of `doOnNext()` either just `post()` to main thread `Handler` or via Rx:

```
observable.doOnNext(() -> {
  Completable
    .fromCallable(() -> information.saveSomething(v))
    .subscribeOn(mainThread())
    .subscribe();
})
```

Comment: Oh, nice solution! I've been hoping to find something like this - rx based, because some emulators have some runtimes which cause leaks when doing `View.post()`. Or something like it, but I remember having problems. And also it would require passing `View/Context` around which oftentimes smells.